# Why is my Aleart Message not appearing after the user login wasn't correct? Django, html, css

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

This is the Script in my signIn.html

```
{% if messg %}
<script>
  aleart("{{messg}}");
</script>
{% endif %}
```

This is my Django View

```
def postsign(request): 
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    passw = request.POST.get("pass")
    try:
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,passw)
    except:
        message="Invalid credentials - try again"
        return render(request, "signIn.html", {"messg":message})
    print(user)
    return render(request, "welcome.html", {"e":email})

def signIn(request):
    return render(request, "signIn.html")
```

I was expecting an Aleart message on my screen that the Login was not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure, but i think you got the wrong spell. Can you change spells aleart to alert?

Comment: Wow. What a simple fix - I guess I had too much programming for today. Altough I was reading x times over it I couldn't see the typo. Thank you very much! :-)